# Retrieve data from last line in vmware.log file?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, powercli, vcenter

I currently have a script that retrieves the last modified date of the .vmx in a VM's datastore in vCenter. I need to make changes to instead use and display the last date in the vmware.log file (located in the same datastore as the .vmx)

I'm not sure how to grab that line and convert it to a XX/XX/XXXX format. In the log file, it shows it as Dec 23 10 for example. If this is not possible, no worries. I just need to pull the last line in the log file and export it to a .csv file. Below is my current code:

```
add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core

# ---------- Only modify the fields in this area -------------
$vCenter = 'qlab-copsmgr'                  #name of the vCenter 
$dataCenter = 'Fly-away Kit'               #name of the DataCenter 
$outputFile = $vCenter + '-LastDateUsed.csv'             #desired output file name

# ---------- No modification is needed in the below code. Do not edit   -------------
$columnName = "Name,DataStore,Date Last Used" | Out-File .\$OutputFile -Encoding ascii
Connect-VIServer $vCenter -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
$vmList = Get-VM | where { $_.PowerState -eq “PoweredOff”} | select Name
$vmList = $vmList -replace 'Name : ', '' -replace '@{Name=', '' -replace '}', ''

ForEach ($VM in $vmList)
{
    # Get configuration and path to vmx file
    $VMconfig = Get-VM $VM | Get-View | select config
    $VMXpath = $VMconfig.config.files.VMpathName

    # Remove and/or replace unwanted strings
    $VMXpath = $VMXpath -replace '\[','' -replace '\] ','\' -replace '@{Filename=','/' -replace '}','' -replace '/','\'

    # List the vmx file in the datastore
    $VMXinfo = ls vmstores:\$VCenter@443\$DataCenter\$VMXpath | Where {$_.LastWriteTime} | select -first 1 | select FolderPath, LastWriteTime

    # Remove and/or replace unwanted strings
    $VMXinfo = $VMXinfo -replace 'DatastoreFullPath=', '' -replace '@{', '' -replace '}', '' -replace ';', ',' -replace 'LastWriteTime=', ''

    # Output vmx information to .csv file
    $output = $VM + ', ' + $VMXinfo
    $output
    echo $output >> $OutputFile
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with an example last line from your log file.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to pull the last event from the vmware.log file in order to backtrack the power off time for VMs where there is no vCenter event history. I looked at file timestamps but found that some VM processes and possibly backup solutions can make them useless.

I tried reading the file in place but ran into issues with the PSDrive type not supporting Get-Content in place. So for better or worse for my solution I started with one of LucD's scripts - the 'Retrieve the logs' script from http://www.lucd.info/2011/02/27/virtual-machine-logging/ which pulls a VMs vmware.log file and copies it to local storage. I then modified it to copy the vmware.log file to a local temp folder, read the last line from the file before deleting the file and return the last line of the log as a PS object.

Note, this is slow and I'm sure my hacks to LucD's script are not elegant, but it does work and I hope if helps someone.

Note: This converts the time value from the log to a PS date object by simple piping the string timestamp from the file into Get-Date. I've read that this does not work as expected for non-US date formatting. For those outside of the US you might want to look into this or just pass the raw timestamp string from the log instead of converting it.

```
#Examples:
#$lastEventTime = (Get-VM -Name "SomeVM" | Get-VMLogLastEvent).EventTime
#$lastEventTime = Get-VMLogLastEvent -VM "SomeVM" -Path "C:\alternatetemp\"

function Get-VMLogLastEvent{
    param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][PSObject[]]$VM,
    [string]$Path=$env:TEMP
    )

    process{   
        $report = @()

        foreach($obj in $VM){
            if($obj.GetType().Name -eq "string"){
                $obj = Get-VM -Name $obj
            }
            $logpath = ($obj.ExtensionData.LayoutEx.File | ?{$_.Name -like "*/vmware.log"}).Name
            $dsName = $logPath.Split(']')[0].Trim('[')
            $vmPath = $logPath.Split(']')[1].Trim(' ')
            $ds = Get-Datastore -Name $dsName
            $drvName = "MyDS" + (Get-Random)
            $localLog = $Path + "\" + $obj.Name + ".vmware.log"
            New-PSDrive -Location $ds -Name $drvName -PSProvider VimDatastore -Root '\' | Out-Null
            Copy-DatastoreItem -Item ($drvName + ":" + $vmPath) -Destination $localLog -Force:$true
            Remove-PSDrive -Name $drvName -Confirm:$false

            $lastEvent = Get-Content -Path $localLog -Tail 1
            Remove-Item -Path $localLog -Confirm:$false

            $row = "" | Select VM, EventType, Event, EventTime
            $row.VM = $obj.Name
            ($row.EventTime, $row.EventType, $row.Event) = $lastEvent.Split("|")
            $row.EventTime = $row.EventTime | Get-Date
            $report += $row
         }
         $report        
    }
}
```

That should cover your request, but to expound further on why I needed the detail, which reading between the lines may also benefit you, I'll continue.

I inherited hundreds of legacy VMs that have been powered off from various past acquisitions and divestitures and many of which have been moved between vCenter instances losing all event log detail. When I started my cleanup effort in just one datacenter I had over 60TB of powered off VMs. With the legacy nature of these there was also no detail available on who owned or had any knowledge of these old VMs.

For this I hacked another script I found, also from LucD here: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/540397.

This will take in all the powered off VMs, attempt to determine the time powered off via vCenter event history. I modified it to fall back to the above Get-VMLogLastEvent function to get the final poweroff time of the VM if event log detail is not available.

Error catching could be improved - this will error on VMs where for one reason or another there is no vmware.log file. But quick and dirty I've found this to work and provides the detail on what I need for over 90%.

Again this relies on the above function and for me at least the errors just fail through passing through null values. One could probably remove the errors by adding a check for vmware.log existance before attempting to copy it though this would add a touch more latency in execution due to the slow PSDrive interface to datastores.

```
$Report = @()  

$VMs = Get-VM | Where {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOff"}  
$Datastores = Get-Datastore | Select Name, Id  
$PowerOffEvents = Get-VIEvent -Entity $VMs -MaxSamples ([int]::MaxValue) | where {$_ -is [VMware.Vim.VmPoweredOffEvent]} | Group-Object -Property {$_.Vm.Name}  

foreach ($VM in $VMs) {  
    $lastPO = ($PowerOffEvents | Where { $_.Group[0].Vm.Vm -eq $VM.Id }).Group | Sort-Object -Property CreatedTime -Descending | Select -First 1 
    $lastLogTime = "";

    # If no event log detail, revert to vmware.log last entry which takes more time...
    if (($lastPO.PoweredOffTime -eq "") -or ($lastPO.PoweredOffTime -eq $null)){
        $lastLogTime = (Get-VMLogLastEvent -VM $VM).EventTime
    }

    $row = "" | select VMName,Powerstate,OS,Host,Cluster,Datastore,NumCPU,MemMb,DiskGb,PoweredOffTime,PoweredOffBy,LastLogTime
    $row.VMName = $vm.Name  
    $row.Powerstate = $vm.Powerstate  
    $row.OS = $vm.Guest.OSFullName  
    $row.Host = $vm.VMHost.name  
    $row.Cluster = $vm.VMHost.Parent.Name  
    $row.Datastore = $Datastores | Where{$_.Id -eq ($vm.DatastoreIdList | select -First 1)} | Select -ExpandProperty Name  
    $row.NumCPU = $vm.NumCPU  
    $row.MemMb = $vm.MemoryMB  
    $row.DiskGb = Get-HardDisk -VM $vm | Measure-Object -Property CapacityGB -Sum | select -ExpandProperty Sum  
    $row.PoweredOffTime = $lastPO.CreatedTime  
    $row.PoweredOffBy   = $lastPO.UserName
    $row.LastLogTime = $lastLogTime
    $report += $row  
}  

# Output to screen  
$report | Sort Cluster, Host, VMName | Select VMName, Cluster, Host, NumCPU, MemMb, @{N='DiskGb';E={[math]::Round($_.DiskGb,2)}}, PoweredOffTime, PoweredOffBy | ft -a  

# Output to CSV - change path/filename as appropriate  
$report | Sort Cluster, Host, VMName | Export-Csv -Path "output\Powered_Off_VMs_Report.csv" -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Cheers!
I pray this pays back some of the karma I've used.

Meyeaard

Answer (score 0):

I have made a script that checks line by line and if string is found changes it to desired format

```
#example input you can use get-content PATH to txt or any file and assign it to $lines variable
$lines = @"
ernfoewnfnsf
ernfoewnfnsf
Dec 23 10 sgdsgdfgsdadasd
"@ -split "\r\n"

#checks line by line and if find anything that maches start of the line, one Big letter two small, space, two digits, space, two digits, space 
$lines | ForEach-Object{

    if ($_ -match "^[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}\s")
    {
        $match = [convert]::ToDateTime($matches[0])
        $_ -replace $matches[0], "$($match.ToShortDateString()) " | out-file { PATH } -APPEND
    }
    else
    {
        $_ | out-file { PATH } -APPEND
    }
}
```

just change {PATH} with a filenamePAth and this should work for you